# Complex integral problem - Two different answers! - $\oint_C\frac{dz}{z(2z+1)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is from Arfken, problem #11.4.8 (7th Edition).

I have to compute the complex integral, $$\oint_C\frac{dz}{z(2z+1)}$$ over the unit circle.

So I took my $f(z)=\frac1{2z+1}$, and my $z_0=0$, and the applied the Cauchy's integral formula, and I get the answer, $2\pi i f(z_0)=2\pi i$. Note my function is *analytic* within the contour $C$.

Now I can do the integral one more way, split the two factors into partial fractions, and do the integral. This way I get, $$\oint_C\frac{dz}{z}-\oint_C\frac{dz}{z+\frac12}=2\pi i - 2 \pi i = 0$$

So clearly, I get two different answers for the same problem. Where am I going wrong?

> Update:

My first work had an issue, fixed it. $f(z)$ had a simple pole at $z=-\frac12$, which was within my contour.

Thank you guys for the prompt response. Didn't see that thing.

Comment: what about the pole $z_0 = -\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Interior of $C$ has $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2z+1}$ is not holomorphic at $z_0=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @AaronMaroja: Oopsie, got it! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy's Formula:

$$\oint_C\frac{dz}{z(2z+1)}=\oint_C\frac{\frac1{2z}}{z+\frac12}dz=\left.2\pi i\frac1{2z}\right|_{z=-\frac12}=-2\pi i$$

Comment: What about $z=0$? Won't $\frac1{2z}$, blow up? And then again, we have two different answers, $0$, and $-2\pi i$.

Comment: I just remarked around the pole $\;z=-\frac12\;$ because that's the one you apparently missed. Around zero we get: $$\oint_{C'}\frac{\frac1{2z+1}}z=\left.2\pi i\frac1{2z+1}\right|_{z=0}=2\pi i$$ and after adding both answers you get zero.